# Inserting a shortcode into a genesis menu?

Tags: php, menus, genesis-theme-framework

I'm trying to insert a shortcode as the last item in a menu but it results in creating the `<li>` but then throwing the shortcode output elsewhere, outside of the list. It also removes the closing `<li>` for that menu item?

In functions.php (as per Jared's answer below)..

```
<?php
    // Add Cart Contents to End of Nav
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','my_item', 11, 2);
    function my_item($items, $args) {
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-last" id="menu-item-last">' . do_shortcode('[shopping_cart empty_msg="You have no items in your basket"]') . '</li>';
        return $items;
    }
?>
```

The output is:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wrap"><div id="title-area"><p id="title"><a title="asdf" href="asdf">asdfy</a></p><p id="description">asdf</p></div><!-- end #title-area -->

You have no items in your basket

<div id="nav"><div class="wrap"><ul class="nav" id="menu-main-navigation-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-91" id="menu-item-91"><a href="asdf">asdf</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29" id="menu-item-29"><a href="asdf">asdf</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2838" id="menu-item-2838"><a href="asdf">asdf</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34" id="menu-item-34"><a href="asdf">asdf</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31" id="menu-item-31"><a href="asdf">asdf</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33" id="menu-item-33"><a href="asdf">asdf</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112" id="menu-item-112"><a href="asdf">asdf</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-last" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-last"/></ul></div><!-- end .wrap --></div></div>
```

Edit: Cart66ShortcodeManager.php

```
  /**
   * Short code for displaying shopping cart including the number of items in the cart and links to view cart and checkout
   */
  public function shoppingCart($attrs) {
    $cartPage = get_page_by_path('store/cart');
    $checkoutPage = get_page_by_path('store/checkout');
    $cart = Cart66Session::get('Cart66Cart');
    if(is_object($cart) && $cart->countItems()) {
      ?>
      <div id="Cart66scCartContents" style="float:right; text-align: right;">
        <a id="Cart66scCartLink" href='<?php echo get_permalink($cartPage->ID) ?>'>
        <span id="Cart66scCartCount"><?php echo $cart->countItems(); ?></span>
        <span id="Cart66scCartCountText"><?php echo $cart->countItems() > 1 ? ' items' : ' item' ?></span> 
        <span id="Cart66scCartCountDash">&ndash;</span>
        <!-- <span id="Cart66scCartPrice"><?php //echo CART66_CURRENCY_SYMBOL . 
          number_format($cart->getSubTotal() - $cart->getDiscountAmount(), 2); ?> -->
        </span></a>
        <a id="Cart66scViewCart" href='<?php echo get_permalink($cartPage->ID) ?>'>View Cart</a>
        <span id="Cart66scLinkSeparator"> | </span>
        <a id="Cart66scCheckout" href='<?php echo get_permalink($checkoutPage->ID) ?>'>Check out</a>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
    else {
      $emptyMessage = isset($attrs['empty_msg']) ? $attrs['empty_msg'] : 'Your cart is empty';
        //echo "<p id=\"Cart66scEmptyMessage\" style=\"float:right; text-align: right;\">$emptyMessage</p>";
        echo "$emptyMessage";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Moderators: Please remove this question as I will be throwing it over to StackOverflow. Thank you

Comment: Actually, I can just move this over tho SO for you ... would you rather have me delete it or migrate it?

Comment: @EAMann: EAMann, thank you! Probably best that the other one is deleted or migrated, it seems that Jared has provided an answer that I will accept. Just about to test it :) Thanks!

Comment: If you've already got a good answer here, there's no need to migrate! :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the fact that you are trying to echo something into a string, `echo` should only be used to output something, so simply change the following line:

```
$items .= '<li class="myclass">' . echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]') . '</li>';
```

To this:

```
$items .= '<li class="myclass">' . do_shortcode('[shopping_cart]') . '</li>';
```

**Edit:** <s>On another note, this is merely a PHP question, such questions should be asked at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).</s>

**Edit 2:** In regards to your last edit on your question, shortcode functions need to `return` data, not `echo` it, this is what is causing the issue. You would need to take everything you are `echo`ing and put it into a variable instead, and then `return` that variable (which contains the HTML code you want to output).

```
/**
 * Short code for displaying shopping cart including the number of items in the cart and links to view cart and checkout
 */
public function shoppingCart( $attrs ) {

    $cartPage = get_page_by_path( 'store/cart' );
    $checkoutPage = get_page_by_path( 'store/checkout' );
    $cart = Cart66Session::get( 'Cart66Cart' );

    if( is_object( $cart ) && $cart->countItems() ) {

        $buffer = '<div id="Cart66scCartContents" style="float:right; text-align: right;">';
        $buffer .= '<a id="Cart66scCartLink" href="' . get_permalink( $cartPage->ID ) . '">';
        $buffer .= '<span id="Cart66scCartCount">' . $cart->countItems() . '</span>';
        $buffer .= '<span id="Cart66scCartCountText">' . $cart->countItems() > 1 ? ' items' : ' item' . '</span> ';
        $buffer .= '<span id="Cart66scCartCountDash">&ndash;</span>';
        $buffer .= '<!-- <span id="Cart66scCartPrice">' . CART66_CURRENCY_SYMBOL.number_format($cart->getSubTotal() - $cart->getDiscountAmount(), 2).'</span></a> -->';
        $buffer .= '<a id="Cart66scViewCart" href="' . get_permalink( $cartPage->ID ) . '">View Cart</a>';
        $buffer .= '<span id="Cart66scLinkSeparator"> | </span>';
        $buffer .= '<a id="Cart66scCheckout" href="' . get_permalink( $checkoutPage->ID ) . '">Check out</a>';
        $buffer .= '</div>';
        return $buffer;

    } else {

        $emptyMessage = isset( $attrs['empty_msg'] ) ? $attrs['empty_msg'] : 'Your cart is empty';
        return "<p id=\"Cart66scEmptyMessage\" style=\"float:right; text-align: right;\">" . $emptyMessage . "</p>";

    }

}​
```

Comment: Thank you Jared! You're right- just thought it would have something to do with the genesis framework. It worked, however not quite as it should, as it doesn't insert the shortcode output in the <li>, rather outside of it? I'll update my questions now..

Comment: @iCeR The new problem that has risen from this may in fact be a WordPress question. Can you update your question with the function that displays the `[shopping_cart]` shortcode?

Comment: Sure! Placing it in there now. You will find my commented out code where I stripped all styling so it just echo's the variable..

Comment: @iCeR See my last edit. :)

Comment: thank you Jared! Just to be sure I get you.. I now do: `$cartoutput = echo do_shortcode('[shopping_cart empty_msg="You have no items in your basket"]');` and then `$items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-last" id="menu-item-last">' . $cartoutput . '</li>';` ?

Comment: @iCeR I updated my answer again with what your shortcode's function _should_ look like. Just remember, `echo` means display on the page, you can't do `$somevar = echo 'blah';`, it is just not logical. You make variables to return things or do other things with them, anything but `echo`. ;)

Comment: Aha! @Jared you are a champion. It completely slipped under the radar that I was echo'ing rather than returning the data held within the $emptyMessage variable! Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)